$\int_0^1 \sqrt{\frac{2-x^4}{1-x^4}}\, dx$ in terms of the gamma function or elliptic integrals
Question
Can
$$\int_0^1 \sqrt{\frac{2-x^4}{1-x^4}}\, dx$$
be expressed in closed form in terms of the gamma function at rational arguments or in closed form in terms of elliptic integrals?
Thoughts
Unexpectedly, when working on it, I ended up discovering a different result:
$$\int_0^1 \sqrt{\frac{2+x^2-x^4}{1-x^4}}\, dx=\frac{4\sqrt{2\pi^3}}{\Gamma (-1/4)^2}+\frac{\Gamma (3/4)^2}{\sqrt{2\pi}}.$$
I have no idea if the above result is known. But the first integral seems much harder.
A CAS gave a result for the first integral, in terms of the Gaussian hypergeometric function:
$$\frac{\pi^{3/2}\operatorname{F}\left(1/4,5/4,3/4,-1\right)}{2^{3/4}\Gamma (3/4)^2}$$
but I don't know if the $\operatorname{F}$ term has a closed form in terms of the gamma function or elliptic integrals.
It's a near miss: Change the $3/4$ to $-3/4$ and:
$$\operatorname{F}\left(\frac{1}{4},\frac{5}{4},-\frac{3}{4},-1\right)=\frac{11}{12\cdot 2^{1/4}}$$
When trying to transform the first integral to the second (known) integral, I managed to prove that
$$\begin{align}\int_0^1 \sqrt{\frac{2-x^4}{1-x^4}}\, dx&=\int_0^1 \sqrt{\frac{1+6x^2+x^4}{1-x^4}}\frac{dx}{1+x^2}\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\pi/2}\sqrt{\frac{2}{\sin x}-\sin x}\, dx\end{align}$$
but I'm stuck.

The second integral is elliptic:$$\begin{align*}\int_0^1\sqrt{\frac{2+x^2-x^4}{1-x^4}},dx&=\int_0^\infty\sqrt{\frac{2+y^2}{\left(1+y^2\right)^3}},dy&x=\frac y{\sqrt{1+y^2}}\
&=\sqrt2\sqrt{1-\frac12\sin^2z},dz=\sqrt2,E\left(\frac1{\sqrt2}\right)&y=\tan z\end{align*}$$See the equivalent form here.

... or more immediately, $x=\sin z$

@user170231 Can you at least prove that the first integral is not elliptic?

No, I've not been able to. I think it may be an inextricable hypergeometric function. WA gives an antiderivative in terms of the Appell series but I can't quite get it to evaluate the definite integral. OTOH in the past I've evaluated integrals similar to the last one, $\sqrt{2\csc x-\sin x}$, that did admit elliptic forms, so I'm somewhat optimistic that there is an elliptic integral hiding in there.

@Kraken Your integral evaluates to $2E(1/\sqrt{2})$, which would mean you solved it! But how did you arrive at that integral?

@Kraken Your integral is different from the target

I see, @Nomas2 he's right. Currently at $$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \sec^2 \theta \sqrt{3- \sin^2 \theta - \sec^2 \theta} d \theta $$

Too long for comment and not really an answer to the central question, but here is how we can recover the hypergeometric result:
$$\begin{align*}
I &= \int_0^1 \sqrt{\frac{2-x^4}{1-x^4}} \, dx \\
&= \frac12 \int_0^\tfrac\pi2 \sqrt{\frac{2-\sin^2x}{\sin x}} \, dx \\
&= \frac1{2^{1/4}} \int_0^\tfrac\pi4 \frac{1-\sin^2y}{\sqrt{\sin y} \sqrt{1-2\sin^2y}} \, dy & \sin x=\sqrt2\,\sin y \\
&= \frac1{2^{1/4}} \int_0^1 \frac{dz}{z^{1/2} \left(1-z^2\right)^{1/2} \left(1+z^2\right)^{5/4}} & \tan y=z \\
&= \frac1{2^{5/4}} \int_0^1 \frac{dz}{z^{3/4} (1-z)^{1/2} (1+z)^{5/4}} & z\to\sqrt z \\
&= \frac1{2^{5/4}} \int_0^1 z^{-3/4} (1-z)^{-1/2} \, {}_2 F_1\left(\begin{matrix}\frac54,\beta\\\beta\end{matrix} ; -z\right) \, dz & (1) \\
&= \frac1{2^{5/4}} \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac14\right)\Gamma\left(\frac12\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac34\right)} \, {}_2F_1 \left(\begin{matrix}\frac14,\frac54\\\frac34\end{matrix} ; -1\right) & (2) \\
&= \frac1{2^{7/4}\sqrt\pi} \Gamma\left(\frac14\right)^2 \, {}_2F_1 \left(\begin{matrix}\frac14,\frac54\\\frac34\end{matrix} ; -1\right) & \Gamma\text{ reflection formula}
\end{align*}$$
$(1)$ and $(2)$ follow from identities listed in Gradshteyn and Ryzhik's Table of Integrals, Series, and Products,
$${}_2F_1 \left(\begin{matrix}-n,\beta\\\beta\end{matrix} ; -z\right) = (1+z)^n \tag1$$
$$\int_0^1 (1-x)^{\mu-1} x^{\nu-1} {}_pF_q \left(\begin{matrix}a_1,\ldots,a_p\\\nu,b_2,\ldots,b_q\end{matrix} ; ax\right) \, dx \\
= \frac{\Gamma(\mu)\Gamma(\nu)}{\Gamma(\mu+\nu)} {}_pF_q \left(\begin{matrix}a_1,\ldots,a_p\\\mu+\nu,b_2,\ldots,b_q\end{matrix} ;  a\right) \tag2$$

Whether it's simpler is a matter of taste, but the leading factors in the result after using (2) can equivalently be expressed as $2^{-7/4}\pi^{-1/2}\Gamma(1/4)^2$.

I'll give you the bounty, as it's been 6 days of the bountied question without an answer. Maybe $\operatorname{F}(1/4,5/4,3/4,-1)$ is the best we can get out of that integral...

@Nomas2 Too kind, much appreciated! Perhaps someone more knowledgeable will come along sooner or later to shed some more light :)
